# How do I animate a spritesheet in cocos2d Android

Tags: android, cocos2d

I'm trying to animate a sprite in a spritesheet, the goal is to make the character walk from left to right. I subclassed CCSprite: CharacterSprite.

this is my code:

```
    CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().addSpriteFrames("WalkAnimation.plist");
    CCSpriteSheet spriteSheet = CCSpriteSheet.spriteSheet("WalkAnimation.png");
    w.addChild(spriteSheet);

    ArrayList<CCSpriteFrame> walkSprites = new ArrayList<CCSpriteFrame>();
    for(int i = 1; i<=8;++i)
    {
        walkSprites.add(CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().spriteFrameByName("walk"+ i +".png"));
    }
    //float randomFactor = (float)Math.random()*10;  
    CCAnimation walkAnimation = CCAnimation.animation("walk", 0.1f, walkSprites);

    Log.v("addEnemy", "Show");
    this.character = CCSprite.sprite(walkSprites.get(0));

    Log.v("addEnemy", "Don't Show");


    this.walkAction = CCRepeatForever.action(CCAnimate.action(walkAnimation, false));
    character.runAction(walkAction);        

    for(int k =0; k<amount; k++)
    {
        float randomFactor = (float)Math.random()*10;
        character.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(-randomFactor * character.getContentSize().width/2, winSize.height / 6.0f));
        spriteSheet.addChild(character);
    }
```

This code is in my 2nd scene. And whenever I press on Start Game, nothing happens. But the code is executed till: 
character = CharacterSprite.sprite("walk1.png");

Can someone provide me of a snippet of animation using a spritesheet?

Comment: "But the code is executed till: character = CharacterSprite.sprite("walk1.jpg");" wht does this mean? Do you mean code is not executed after that statement?

Comment: I tried to Log something after that statement and nothing happened, if I replace CharacterSprite with CCSprite nothing happens aswell. I don't know if I have subclassed it correctly that's why I tried CCSprite too.

Comment: I've changed my code

Comment: hey can you check once the log by enabling Cocos2d Debug variable???

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Is 1.png and 2.png etc.. are different images or you have a single spritesheet "walk1.png" ?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem.
the images referred from the plist are called 1.png etc
while I put in walk1.png

Comment: +1 for preventing Community ♦ from bumping this question again.